# How to load an URL in UIWebView with self-signed certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, uiwebview

My app has a `UIWebView` and it should open a website that contains SSL.
If I open such a website I get an error displayed and after that I still want open that website.

I found a lot of stuff but nothing solved my problem, e.g. [Delegate method didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692259/delegate-method-didreceiveauthenticationchallenge-is-not-getting-called), [UIWebView to view self signed websites (No private api, not NSURLConnection) - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i), [Create SSL connection using certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141226/create-ssl-connection-using-certificate/17146532#17146532) or [iOS HTTPS requests 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033525/ios-https-requests-101) and a lot of other sites.

The server certificate is self-signed. My target of iOS version is 8 and 9. Does ist contain any difference between this two version? I don't know how to implement it. Every time I'm starting my application I get the following error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

## EDIT:

SSL has the requirements iOS version > 9 needs (TLS >= 1.2, connection ciphers supports PFS, requires certificate with SHA-256 fingerprints mit 2048bit+ RSA || 256bit+ ECC (elliptic curve) and the accepted ciphers)

Comment: Go to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i

Comment: does your website is TLS >=1.2 if not then add the row in info.plist to allow to load site which are not having TLS>=1.2 as below <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: @AkashKR Thx that solved my problem. Can't believe I didn't find it ...

Comment: @ArunGupta That doesn't solved my problem. Everything is up-to-date

Comment: @Premox It Happens!!

Comment: Actually `NSURLConnection` is deprecated from iOS 9.